# Why is it that the wind over land in day(low pressure) move to the sea(high pressure)?

Tags: pressure, atmospheric-science

According to my understanding, wind moves from its region of higher pressure to its region of lower pressure. So during sea breeze, cold wind over the sea(high pressure) blows to the land(low pressure) . But why is that the hot wind over the land(low pressure) blows towards the sea(high pressure).

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_breeze help to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

During day land gets heated up and the warmer air rises up creating a Low pressure . To occupy that space air over the sea blows from sea to land and when the air near sea surface had flown to land that space has a Low pressure due to which the air at a higher altitude over sea has to sink down creating a Low pressure at a height where from nearby the hot air which had initially left land comes 
Overall its a cyclic process